# Commuting Bounded linear projections

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, projection

Let $X$ be a Banach (or a Hilbert) space, $T,P\in L(X)$ are bounded linear operators such that $P^{2}=P$ and the operator $TP-PT$ has a finite rank. I want to construct another projection $Q\in L(X)$ (from $P$ and $T$) such that $T$ commute with $Q?$

Comment: That's quite a loose requirement, as stated. For instance, $Q=I-P$ foots the bill.

Comment: No sir $T(I-P)-(I-P)T=PT-TP$

Comment: Fair enough. But your requirement is still too loose, as you can take $Q=I$.